# Powered Link by Manychat on Facebook Messenger How to Remove?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I already remove ManyChat on my client Facebook Page Messenger and replace it with a new bot but the problem is it still shows the powered by manychat (see screenshot)
[image]
I cannot find any option in facebook page setting for this part, are there any documentation or how-to instruction to delete this part?

thanks,

Comment: That looks like the ManyChat bot is still active on the page. Did you properly removed it from the list of subscribed applications …?

Comment: yes I do remove it. Is there a documentation on API that add this option? if yes I might need to do it via API graph.

Comment: Via the [`/page/subscribed_apps`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/subscribed_apps/) endpoint you can check which apps are currently subscribed to the page. (But removing a subscription seems to require an app access token for the app in question.)

Comment: I already check in FB graph explorer and manychat is already remove and not on the list.

Comment: Then it’s likely that they have set this as the greeting for your bot or something - that seems to be a per-page setting, rather than per app. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api

Comment: I think its now fix after trying Manychat connecting and disconnecting it at least 5 times and it remove all setting. Now my problem is it remove all necessary message and info that my current  bot provided added. (will try to install it again via api) Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174828/discussion-between-eggy-and-cbroe).

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the chatbot's persistent menu. This can be done with sending a POST HTTP request to Facebook Messenger API as explained here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/persistent-menu

This worked for another user in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55312936/how-to-remove-powered-by-manychat-footer-from-a-messenger-bot/56330372#56330372).