# How to Remove “Powered by ManyChat” footer from a messenger bot

Tags: messenger

[image]

I am developing a chat bot for the messenger platform, but I found myself mesmerized by the fact that “ManyChat” appears on the footer of the users text input field.

I have become an admin of that page and proceed to remove many chat from the list of connected apps for that page, but the footer is still there.

Maybe I have to call the messenger platform API in order to change some property that isn’t available from the Facebook Pages User Interface. But nothing in the documentation mentions anything about a persistent footer on the page.

Does anyone have any clue of how to remove this?

Comment: How did you use this input text? (This is not Facebook's normal input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to reset the chatbot's persistent menu? This can be done with sending a POST HTTP request to Facebook Messenger API as explained here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages/persistent-menu

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: You’re right, the persistent menu is the culprit. Thanks!